# Glassfish installation JRE not found

Tags: windows, glassfish, java

I can't install Oracle Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2
When I run the installer (as admin) a dialog box appears saying "extracting files" and then I get the following error box saying I don't have JRE installed.

[image: JRE needed]

I have JRE and JDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed (all are 64 bit).
All are in the PATH system variable.
I've tried the program from CMD using the instructions in the error.
The command I use to run is:
`OracleGlassfishServer(OGS)-3.1.2.2-windows.exe" -j "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`
I've also tried with the 1.6 bin.
I am running Win 7 64 bit.

The only thing I haven't thought to try yet was installing a 32bit JRE in the Program Files(x86) directory. Does it make sense that this would require a 32bit JRE?

What else could be the cause?

Comment: As per the comment in the dialog, have you tried to manually specify the JDK installation directory?

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to add that in the comment. I get the same error dialog when I do that.

Comment: Which folder did you pass in the manual invocation?

Comment: `OracleGlassfishServer(OGS)-3.1.2.2-windows.exe" -j "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`  
I've also tried with the 1.6 bin

Comment: Try passing the root of the JRE folder, instead of the bin subfolder.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How do I do that?

Comment: instead of `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`, pass `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09`

Comment: The Glassfish installation program requires the path to the JRE installation folder to be in the JAVA_HOME environment variable; if the variable is not set the folder can be specified on the command line. In both cases the folder must be the root folder of the JRE, not the bin subfolder.

Comment: Thanks Remigio, please place that as an answer and I'll mark as correct. That was what I needed. When I ran the cmd install method with using the root of the folder, not the bin, it worked. Cheers.

Comment: I've edited the answer, thanks for appreciating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Glassfish installation program requires the path to the JRE installation folder to be in the JAVA_HOME environment variable; if the variable is not set the folder can be specified on the command line. In both cases the folder must be the root folder of the JRE, not the bin subfolder.

Comment: If you are still getting the error for path not being valid. add double quotes around the path.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I found setting JAVA_HOME to be ineffective for me.

The solution that worked on my server was to run the Glassfish install with the -j option pointing to my JDK.

Answer (score 0):

using command line and pointing to JRE installation directory should work Just fine, the problem with the above command is that you were pointing to bin directory, simply point to the home directory that is  "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"